# Concatenating the contents of a joined table and project into a view model in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am looking to concatenate the contents of a joined table and project into a view model using LINQ to SQL and C#.

My pseudo-code is as follows:

```
 return (from t1 in db.Opportunities
                    from t2 in db.Leads.Where(x => x.Lead_ID == t1.Lead_ID)
                    from t3 in db.LeadAddresses.Where(x => x.Lead_ID == t2.Lead_ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from t4 in db.Addresses.Where(x => x.Address_ID == t3.Address_ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    orderby (t1.Created) descending
                    select new FieldSalesPipelineViewModel
                    {
                        Id = t1.Opportunity_ID,
                        CompanyName = t2.Company_Name,
                        OpportunityTitle = t1.Opportunity_Title,
                        CompanyCity = ??????????
                    }).Take(howMany);
```

> One lead may have many addresses, but I only want to return one city result
>   in my output, a comma seperated list of *unique* cities from Addresses
>   (t4.City)

Any tips on how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to join multiple cities from t4 into a single string, and put that in CompanyCity? If so, this should do the trick:

```
CompanyCity = string.Join(",", t4.Cities)
```

Comment: Great. Will this yield one result per Opportunity or do I need to do some grouping magic?

Comment: @Nick I think I'd need to see the tables/objects you're joining to answer that for sure. Adding this will keep the record count the same as it would be if you ran your query posted above with the `CompanyCity = ???` line commented out.